# When you run db:seed, where is the script that inserts seed data into the db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

When you run `db:seed`, where is the script that inserts seed data into the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
db/seeds.rb
```

It's usually created by default in a new rails application.